# Modifying "User interface sound effects" with applescript

Tags: audio, applescript

Good morning all,
I would like to be able to turn the system sounds on my mac off (and back on) with an applescript activated as an extension for [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com).

I have little knowledge of applescripts but I have found that I can open the system preference pane. How do I check and uncheck the "Play user interface sound effects" and "Play feedback when volume is changed" check boxes?
[image]

The start of my code is as follows

```
tell application "System Preferences" to activate (reveal anchor "effects" of pane id "com.apple.preference.sound")
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System Preferences and the Sounds prefpane don't have direct ways to script this. But you can use regular UI scripting in AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "effects" of pane id "com.apple.preference.sound"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        if value of theBox is not 1 then
            click checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of window 1
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

Or if you want to set a certain value rather than just toggle the checkbox:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "effects" of pane id "com.apple.preference.sound"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        set theBox to checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of window 1
        if value of theBox is not 1 then -- or "is 1"
            click theBox
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

You can also explicitly say `checkbox "Play user interface sound effects" of ...` instead of just `checkbox 1`, but I'm not sure how this behaves with localizations.

Comment: Ahh ok, "click checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of window 1" is the bit I needed and didn't understand.  Thank you